# Is retention period not supported for tumbling windows in ksqldb?

Tags: ksqldb

I can't seem to figure out why my create table statement fails:

```
ksql> create table rst_wind_2 as select id, avg(intensity), min(rowtime) as `from` from rst2 WINDOW TUMBLING (SIZE 5 SECONDS, RETENTION 7 DAYS) group by id emit changes;
line 1:119: mismatched input ',' expecting ')'
Statement: create table rst_wind_2 as select id, avg(intensity), min(rowtime) as `from` from rst2 WINDOW TUMBLING (SIZE 5 SECONDS, RETENTION 7 DAYS) group by id emit changes;
Caused by: line 1:119: mismatched input ',' expecting ')'
Caused by: org.antlr.v4.runtime.InputMismatchException
```

I've gone and had a look at the [grammar](https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/blob/a21e89d2c22215f2a8f677b00932463a0c5f21c8/ksqldb-parser/src/main/antlr4/io/confluent/ksql/parser/SqlBase.g4), but it looks like it should work.

Removing the RETENTION part makes it work, so somehow it just can't parse.

This is version 5.5 (typed version in the ksql command line), so the latest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version of ksqlDB that ships with Confluent Platform v5.5 does not support the RETENTION syntax. See the [5.5 grammer](https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/blob/5.5.x/ksqldb-parser/src/main/antlr4/io/confluent/ksql/parser/SqlBase.g4).

It looks like this was introduced in ksqlDB version 0.8. The upcoming Confluent Platform release, v6.0.0, will ship with ksqlDB 0.10 and will support the RETENTION syntax.

If you require RETENTION either wait for CP 6.0.0 or use one of the community releases of ksqlDB v0.8 or later.

Comment: For completeness, I was using the 5.5 images from the [docker-compose file](https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-all-in-one/blob/5.5.0-post/cp-all-in-one/docker-compose.yml) from the confluent repo. The 6.0.0 docker-compose file is available, but there are no published images on dockerhub at this time. I can't find the community releases anywhere.

Comment: ksqlDB community images are on docker hub.  e.g. 0.9 is https://hub.docker.com/layers/confluentinc/ksqldb-server/0.9.0/images/sha256-5b2bef312055212eaeefd24c60a417ca46b50173611fee7f2afbc980f9b3bd02?context=explore

Comment: Cool! It looks like they are incompatible with the platform release versions, or there are at least enough differences that I'll have to change stuff to get it working again. But we'll get there.Thanks!

Comment: No problem. Happy streaming.